# What is $|a H a^{-1}|$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Assume that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $a \in G$, let $a H a^{-1} = \{a h a^{-1} | h \in H \}$ be a subgroup of $G$. What is $|a H a^{-1}|$?

My opinion: Since $h$ is any element of $H$. We could conclude that $|a H a^{-1}| = |H|$. Is that true?

Comment: Perhaps you might try to *prove* the map $h \mapsto aha^{-1}$ is a bijection?

Comment: Now I undestand it, we must construct a function $h \mapsto a h a^{-1}$ and prove it is a bijection to conclude $|a H a^{-1}| = H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Define function $I_a\colon G \to G$ with formula $I_a(g) =aga^{-1}$. What can you say about that function? Note that $I_a(H) = aHa^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g: H \to a H a^{-1}$ by $g(h) =aha^{-1}$. Show that $g$ is a bijection and conclude that $|a H a^{-1}| = |H|$.

Comment: If you "define" the function like this you need to show that it is well-defined. It is thus better to defined a function the other way round.

Comment: @quid Right. thanks.

Comment: Could you expland why we must show that function is well-defined?

Comment: You can't conclude that something is a bijection if you are not sure that this 'something' is a function. If one has to show that a function is well defined, they actually mean that they are showing that the function is a function.